# How many numbers are there in partial collections $C$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $U$ be a set of natural number $U=\{m|1≤m<1000\}$ and $C$ be a partial collection $C=\{m\in U|m^2\equiv 0 (mod 8)\}$.
The point is, how many numbers are there in $C$? I have no idea what should I do to count this. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you can try to evaluate the expression $m^2 \mod{8}$ for some small values of $m$. Maybe you'll see a pattern ...

Comment: I'll leave a hint: If $n$ is divisible by $4$, then $n^2$ is divisible by $8$